# Angular router - empty data object for child routes

Tags: angular, angular-router

My angular router needs to use the same component for both the parent & child route, but pass along data to differentiate between the parent and child routes.

**Current issue:** the child route does not register any data from the sub-route.

*Routing module segment that defines relationship:*

```
{
        path: 'parent-path/:id',
        component: MyComponent,
        children: [{
          path: 'child-path'
          component: MyComponent,
          data: {MY_DATA_KEY: MY_DATA_VALUE},
        }]
},
```

*In the angular component:*

```
constructor(
      //...
      private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
      //...
) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data', data);  // This prints and empty object //

      /* ... do something with data */
   });
}
```

**Current behaviour:**

*on hitting route '.../parent-path/some-id'*

- normal expected behaviour, no data present

*on hitting route '.../parent-path/some-id/child-path'*

- unexpected behaviour, data is still empty

**Note:** I also tried adding data at the parent level, which does get registered at both routes. Relatively new to angluar, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you build a simple blitz to demonstrate your issue? That could help us better understand what is not working for you. Thx.

Comment: I see `MyComponent` used twice in the routing, is that correct?
Also, have you tried using `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data`?

Comment: Yes, the parent and child routes should render the same component. I'm finding that the activatedRoute is returning the parent node instead of the child node at the sub-route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular's router is essentially a tree structure with parents and children, data is defined at the nodes in that tree, and the data objects exist at the specific nodes where they're defined. so a parent route will not see a child route data in it's own 'data', nor will the child routes see it's parent 'data' directly.  But you can access the parent / child routes from the activated route as needed

```
this.route.parent.data.subscribe(pd => console.log(pd, 'parent data'));
```

or

```
this.route.children.forEach(c => c.data.subscribe(cd => console.log(cd, 'child data'));
```

here is a stackblitz demonstrating the behavior: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s4mffg?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Ended up having to use `this.route.children...`, but I am still struggling to understand why activedRoute would return the parent node in this case? Not sure if you have any clarity there @bryan60

Comment: the activated route injected into a component is the activated route at the node in the router tree where the route is defined.  so the component on the parent route is getting the route at the parent node and the child is getting the route at the child node