# How to use angular router child routes to affect state

Tags: angular, angular-router

Atm I am using Angular router. At the parent route, I have a component render with default state (tabIndex = 0).

*Desired Behaviour:* At a child route, I would like to be able to change the tabIndex state on the same component.

**Options considered**

*1. Using data*

I have successfully been able to differentiate paths by adding `data` and subscribing to the activatedRoute's children's data.

```
this.route.children.forEach(c => c.data.subscribe(cd => console.log(cd, 'child data'))
```

[Angular router - empty data object for child routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57261752/angular-router-empty-data-object-for-child-routes)

*2. Using parameterization*

Someone also suggested that I could use a parameterized subroute and do a regex match.

Routing module segment that defines relationship:

```
{
        path: 'parent-path/:id',
        component: MyComponent,
        children: [{
          path: ':child-path'
          component: MyComponent,
        }]
},
```

--

**What's the best way to accomplish this?**

Neither option feels particularly great, especially since I will have multiple levels of parent/child relationships.  Does anyone have any advice or thoughts.  I haven't been able to find any other meaningful options for this and I am new to ng, so any advice or thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: What is meant by "tabIndex state"

Comment: There's a tabindex state on the component that determines which <mat-tab> is currently active. But there are other use cases, I meant only to provide an example of one.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like using services to communicate between children and parent(s).

//sharedService.ts

```
 private _tabIndex$ = new Subject<number>();
 public tabIndex$ = this._tabIndex$.asObservable();

 ngOnDestroy():void {
     this._tabIndex$.complete();
 }

 setTabIndex(index: number): void {
     // validate it is a number

     this._tabIndex$.next(index);
 }
```

// parentComponent.ts

```
private _destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
constructor(
   private _sharedService: SharedService
){
    this._sharedService.tabIndex$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this._destroy$)
    ).subscribe(index => // do something);
}

ngOnDestroy():void {
    this._destroy$.next();
    this._destroy$.complete();
}
```

// child

```
constructor(
 private _sharedService: SharedService,
 private _route: ActiveRoute
){
  const tabIndex = this._route.snapshot.data.tabIndex || null;
  if(tabIndex != null){
     this._sharedService.setTabIndex(tabIndex);
  }
}
```

The child component will send tabIndex itself.

This code could be put in a generic component class and extend every component that will be send its tabIndex, so you do not have add this code in every component.